# How to remove files when file name too long in Mac OS X

Tags: linux, macos

I tried to find all the conflict files and delete them by the command:

```
find ./ -iname *Air* | xargs -0 rm
```

but it showed me the error ": File name too long"
How could I fix it?

```
.//sandbox/CDF.files/._image002 (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).jpg
.//sandbox/CDF.files/._image003 (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).jpg
.//sandbox/CDF.files/._image004 (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).gif
.//sandbox/CDF.files/._image005 (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).gif
.//sandbox/CDF.files/._item0001 (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).xml
.//sandbox/CDF.files/._props002 (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).xml
.//sandbox/CDF.files/._themedata (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).thmx
.//sandbox/docs/._123CDF (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).htm
.//sandbox/docs/._1CDF (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).html
.//sandbox/docs/._78CDF (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).htm
.//sandbox/docs/._8131CDF (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).htm
.//sandbox/docs/._8173CDF (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).htm
.//sandbox/docs/._All (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).htm
.//sandbox/docs/._FULL_CDF (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).htm
.//sandbox/docs/._LITTLE_CDF (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).htm
.//sandbox/docs/._Simple (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).doc
.//sandbox/docs/._Simple (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).htm
.//sandbox/docs/._simpleCH7_fullCH8 (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).doc
.//sandbox/docs/._simpleCH7_fullCH8 (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).htm
.//sandbox/docs/._URL_Command_List_for_All_Series (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).doc
.//sandbox/docs/._URL_Command_List_for_IP8173H_VVTK (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).doc
.//sandbox/docs/8173CDF.files/._colorschememapping (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).xml
.//sandbox/docs/8173CDF.files/._editdata (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).mso
.//sandbox/docs/8173CDF.files/._filelist (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).xml
.//sandbox/docs/8173CDF.files/._header (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).htm
.//sandbox/docs/8173CDF.files/._image001 (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).gif
.//sandbox/docs/8173CDF.files/._image002 (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).jpg
.//sandbox/docs/8173CDF.files/._image003 (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).jpg
.//sandbox/docs/8173CDF.files/._themedata (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).thmx
.//sandbox/docs/All.files/._colorschememapping (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).xml
.//sandbox/docs/All.files/._filelist (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).xml
.//sandbox/docs/All.files/._header (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).htm
.//sandbox/docs/All.files/._image001 (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).gif
.//sandbox/docs/All.files/._image002 (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).jpg
.//sandbox/docs/All.files/._image003 (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).jpg
.//sandbox/docs/All.files/._image004 (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).gif
.//sandbox/docs/All.files/._image005 (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).gif
.//sandbox/docs/All.files/._item0012 (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).xml
.//sandbox/docs/All.files/._props013 (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).xml
.//sandbox/docs/All.files/._themedata (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).thmx
.//sandbox/v1_no_jumna_sorting/._cdf (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).txt
.//sandbox/v1_no_jumna_sorting/._fussy_cdf (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).txt
.//sandbox/v1_no_jumna_sorting/._word (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).txt
.//sandbox/v2_fuzzy_sorting_without_human/._cdf (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).txt
: File name too long
```

Comment: It is an odd error to get — if the file name exists on the disk, it is almost by definition not too long.  Is the file in fact remote mounted from some other machine?  I took the last component of the name of the last file mentioned (`._cdf (Hsu-Wei-Chengteki-MacBook-Air 的冲突副本 2013-08-19).txt`) and was able to create and remove that file.  It only has 68 bytes in it (58 characters).  I can create a file name with 255 bytes in the last component.

Comment: For anyone still troubling delete long path names, here is my solution. I tried rm mv and it won't work also system-level rename won't work. move any your useful files out from the folder which contains the long-path file, and then "sudo rm -rf folder_which_contain_long_path_file". clean the trash as well. Then re-create the folder and restore your useful files inside the folder. This is the only way I found worked for MAC os Monterey version 12.1 M1 chip

Answer (score 2):

Tell `xargs` to pass fewer characters.

```
... | xargs ... -s 4096 ...
```

Or tell `find` to delete them.

```
find ... -delete
```

Answer (score 1):

```
brew install coreutils
find ./ -iname *Air* | xargs -0 grm
# and you will see the reason
```

or

```
1. find ./ -iname *Air* -delete
   # without nothing output

2. find ./ -iname *Air* -exec rm '{}' \;
```

or

```
xargs -n number
    Set the maximum number of arguments taken from standard input for each invocation of utility.
```